# Can Vent Flashing Nails Be Exposed On The Roof?

Tags: roof, flashing

I am buying a home and as part of the contract we asked for a number of fixes by a certified contractor. For this fix, securing the loose flashing, the home owner said his friend was a contractor so he has no receipt for this specific fix.

The fix entailed 4 exposed nails to secure the flashing. Is this proper/up-to-code/won't-leak?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They probably should be dabbed with roofing cement, but they tend to self-seal to some extent. It's unlikely that they'd leak significantly.

Also concerning is the fact that raw steel nails were used. They'll rust and stain the roof over time. Cement will mostly remedy that as well.

FYI, I don't consider those nails necessary anywhere short of a hurricane zone. Hidden nails and the sealing strips on the shingles hold it all down just fine.

Comment: Shiners are normally covered I like a product called black jack but I agree with isherwood + I normally would not nail the bottom edge.

Comment: Thanks guys. Put Black Jack/roof cement on top of the nail? Or remove the nail and put some in the hole and renail?

Comment: You can just cap it with sealant. It may work loose over extended time, but it will either way.

Comment: I lift the shingle and nail under it then stick shingle back down with black jack